# Target the first child of all instances of a class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 buttons inside of a div.

```
<div class="pull-left address-selector">
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
</div>
```

The class `.address-selector` is found in many places on the page.
How do i select the first child of all the instances of `.address-selector`?

`$(".address-selector a:first").hide();` This just works on the first found instance of `.address-selector`

Comment: So then did you try `$(".address-selector a:first-child")` instead ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`:first-child`](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

> While :first matches only a single element, the :first-child selector can match more than one: one for each parent. This is equivalent to :nth-child(1).

In this case:

```
$(".address-selector a:first-child").hide();
```